# Twilio HTTP Post format for receiving Message

Tags: twilio

I am using Twilio for receiving messages.
Currently using a webhook for incoming messages and can't figure out what's the format of this string.

`ToCountry=GB&ToState=&SmsMessageSid=SM9e341f9cf646bf9ea3b7918e3f422202&NumMedia=0&ToCity=&SmsSid=SM9e341f9cf646bf9e22b7918e3f4r5402&SmsStatus=received&Body=New+Session+https%3A%2F%2Fsss.foo.com%2FDefault.aspx%3Fmt%3Dsms%26sid%3D5f631194-22d8-4d69-87c9-9c90d627aeb9&To=%2B447897031049&ToZip=&NumSegments=1&ReferralNumMedia=0&MessageSid=SM9e322f9cf226bf9ea3b7918e3f4d5702&AccountSid=GFrfb165c1a3c778dsasb6e13eee4a7208&From=foofoo=2012-11-01`

Next, I'll be happy to deserialize it to an object using C# but can't figure out how can I use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio sends to your application using application/x-www-form-urlencoded format.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-faq